# Glue data sets in R

Tags: r, merge

I have two data sets in R. The first one contains a list of time zone names:

[image]

The second one is a list of dates.

[image]

I would like to comnbine them such that the data looks like the following:

[image]

How can I achieve this in R?

Comment: Try `df1$TZ <- df2$TZ`

Comment: `expand.grid(c(df1, df2))`. You can test it with the toy data here: `df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:3); df2 <- data.frame(y = 4:6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code

```r
library(dplyr)

tz %>% full_join(dates, by = character(0))
```